# The development server returned response error code: 500 in basic application in react native

Tags: react-native

I am Android Developer, I am new to react native development. For this, I followed bellow React Native Document

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I did the following steps

1, I have installed node

2, I Have already installed JDK

3, I have installed Android studio

4, set the ANDROID_HOME path in environment variables

And in command prompt, I did run the following commands

> npm install -g react-native-cli

Then create a new application, for this

> react-native init AwesomeProject

Then successfully created the application, then go to that folder and run the application.

```
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

Then getting the following error

[image]

And this is the node js error [image]

So please help me, Thanks In Advance.

Comment: you need to install your `node_modules` again , react-native : 0.46 Version is getting this issue most of time use following command


1)  remove Node_modules first .

2)  **`npm install && npm start --reset-cache`**

Comment: yes did these two steps, but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the workarounds here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968.

Kill the bundler process, delete your modules folder, run `npm install`, `rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache-*`, also rebuild your android project.

If this doesn't work, you can as well try to create your app using create-react-app toolchain which should be working fine : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app .

Comment: modules folder in sample application or node js server?

Comment: In your AwesomeProject folder :)

Comment: also rebuild your android project means need to create new app?

Comment: No, you need to open android studio and clean / rebuild your app OR `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: thank you for your response, but there is no packager/packager.sh --reset-cache in this folder node_modules/react-native

Comment: My bad, I updated my answer to fit the current metro bundler cache !

Comment: what is the problem here, even i dint write any code here, just crate the sample application..but getting every time same issue

Comment: Try to use create-react-app then.

Comment: For this need to install any thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug within Windows environment for React Native `0.56` you may need to upgrade/downgrade your React Native version. I encountered it, made even worse when I tried to use Typescript.

What I would is run a new project using the latest version `0.57` and just build, if it doesn't build straight away - then use `0.55` until the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it was worked for me.

Steps to create New React Native project:

1. `react-native init projectName (ProjectName: eg.HelloWorld)`
2. `cd HelloWorld`
3. `npm start`
4. Open another node command prompt and goto the project path and then run your project with below given command.
5. `react-native run-android`

I think you missed 3rd step i.e to start npm.

And if you are again getting same error, follow these steps:

1. `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
2. `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*`
3. `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`
4. `react-native run-android`